# Why does equating one of the brackets in $(x+1)(x+3)=0$ to zero valid?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When we want to solve an equation like the one given above, we set either $(x+1)$ or $(x+3)$ equal to $0$ to get $x = -1$ or $x = -3$. However, when we put one of those values in the equation, what we end up doing is multiplying the LHS by zero. How is that a valid operation?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, folks! Always the reason why I hate this site. May I know why?

Comment: Let $a$ and $b$ be two real numbers different from zero, then $ab\neq 0$. If $a$ or $b$ is zero, then $ab=0$. Hence $ab=0$ if and only if $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Now you have that $(x+1)(x+3)=0$, hence either $(x+1)=0$ or $(x+3)=0$.

Comment: @Mathematician42 I think I got it. We're not really getting an additional zero and multiplying the equation on both sides with it, we're just using logic to figure out `x`, correct?

Comment: Correct, and I need to write more stuff in order for this comment to appear.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, there is nothing wrong with "multiplying both sides by $0$". We don't do it because it causes a permanent loss of information since it inevitably yields $0=0$, but we could still do it if we wanted to. But in your case, we are not even doing that. The equation asks you to find values for $x$ such that when you compute $(x+1)(x+3)$, the result is $0$, no matter how you arrived at $0$. If it makes you more comfortable, you can expand this to $x^2+4x+3=0$, and plug in the solutions into this form to verify.

Answer (score 1):

We're taking advantage of the [zero-product property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-product_property). The idea is that if we're given the true statement

$$a\dot b = 0$$

Then either $a=0$, $b=0$, or both $a=b=0$. One of these things is true, if the original statement is true. In your example, we probe both factors to see if this is possible. Indeed, $x=-1$ makes $x+1 = 0$ and $x=-3$ makes $x+3=0$. So both factors have zeroes.

This isn't always the case. Consider the true statement

$$\frac1x\dot(x+1)=0$$

In this case, $\frac1x=0$ is never true! It must be the case that $x+1=0$ for some $x$. And yeah, the root is $x=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

"However, when we put one of those values in the equation, what we end up doing is multiplying the LHS by zero. How is that a valid operation?"

That is precisely the point. We want to find a value of $x$ which makes the left side equal the right. If the polynomial is degree two, there are exactly two numbers which make the equality true. This is known as [the fundamental theorem of algebra](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/fundamental-theorem-algebra.html).